# Keep changes when page is reloaded

Tags: php, jquery, css, wordpress, cookies

We have a page built in WP and Oxygen with a function that when you click on an image, the opacity of the image changes (css) with this little script:

```
jQuery(".box,.box1,.box2").click(function () {<br>
      jQuery(this).toggleClass("red"); <br>
});
```

My client wants this to be a "locked" function. So that it never changes on page reload or even upon a blackout or restart of browser or computer. Only when a user clicks on the image.

How can i achieve this? Cookies? Other solution?

Im no coder so as simple as possible please.

Thanks in advance!

I have been playing with this, and it works great with one div but when i add multiple div's they kind of follow each other on page reload so im clearly doing something wrong.

jQuery("#div,#div1,#div2").addClass(localStorage.getItem('ClassName')) ; jQuery("#div,#div1,#div2").on("click",function(){

if(jQuery(this).hasClass('active')){ jQuery(this).removeClass("active").addClass("normal"); localStorage.setItem('ClassName', 'normal'); }

else{ jQuery(this).removeClass("normal").addClass("active");
localStorage.setItem('ClassName', 'active'); } });

Comment: You'd have to persist that information somewhere (cookies is one option, other options include `localStorage` or even server-side), and then check for that information when loading the page.

Comment: I would probably opt for [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage). That is, if you satisfied with storing this in the client. It will get more complex it you want to store it on the server. Please note that this is not code writing service, you need to put a bit of effort in yourself.